# Adding Hyperlink to Google Chart Timeline RowLabel

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, google-visualization

I am working on building a timeline for my teams Project Roadmap.

I have mostly everything setup:  I am embedding the Timeline into our Google Site and it works with everything added so far.

I am hoping to add a link on the RowLabel that will bring me to another page within the Google Site. I have seen some solutions for adding a listener and being able to add a link to a specific row item but I am interested in attaching the link to the RowLabel itself, not the BarLabel.

Google Site example with current timeline implemented: https://sites.google.com/view/timeline-testing/home

What I am hoping to do is:
[Timeline Concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NspC.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var container = document.getElementById('roadmap');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Category' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Project' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true} });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'style', role: 'style' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    
    dataTable.addRows([

      [ 'Category 1', 'Project 1', 
      '<p style="padding:5px"><b>Overall Project:</b> Program X <br><b>Description:</b> Test 
      description for Project 1 <hr> <b> Start:</b> 2020/4/1 <br> <b> End:</b> 2020/8/15</p>', 
      '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 3, 13), new Date(2020, 6, 13)],
      
      [ 'Category 1', 'Project 2',  
      '<p style="padding:5px"><b>Overall Project:</b> Program X <br><b>Description:</b> Test 
      description for Project 2 <hr> <b>Start:</b> 2020/4/1 <br> <b>End:</b> 2020/8/15</p>', 
      '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 4, 22), new Date(2020, 6, 24)],
      
      [ 'Category 1', 'Project 3', "test", '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 6, 13), new Date(2020, 9, 14)],
      [ 'Category 1', 'Project 4', "test", '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 9, 15), new Date(2020, 10, 30)],
      [ 'Category 2', 'Project 1', "test", '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 3, 1), new Date(2020, 4, 14)],
      [ 'Category 2', 'Project 2', "test", '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 4, 14), new Date(2020, 6, 15)],
      [ 'Category 2', 'Project 3', "test", '#00B0F0', new Date(2020, 4, 14), new Date(2020, 10, 30)],
      [ 'Category 3', 'Project 1', "test", '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 3, 1), new Date(2020, 4, 13)],
      [ 'Category 3', 'Project 2', "test", '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 3, 1), new Date(2020, 6, 10)],
      [ 'Category 3', 'Project 3', "test", '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 7, 19), new Date(2020, 10, 30)],
   
    ]);

     var options = {
        tooltip: {isHtml: true},
        legend: 'none'
     };
        
     function selectHandler() {
          var selectedItem = chart.getSelection();
          if (selectedItem = 0) {
            var link = dataTable.getValue(selectedItem.row, 7);
            window.open(link), '_blank');
          }
        }


    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }
</script>

<style>div.google-visualization-tooltip { font-size: 16px; font-family: {"HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", "Arial"}; }</style>
<div id="roadmap" style="height: 100%;"></div>
```

I'm trying to get the selector to recognize the RowLabel being selected.
I also am not sure where to store the link within the DataTable. Should it be another Data Column? I get an error whenever I've tried adding an additional Data Column like:
**dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'link' });**

(separated each line item for easier reading)

```
 dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'link' });
    
    dataTable.addRows([

      [ 'Category 1', 
        'Project 1', 
        '<p style="padding:5px"><b>Overall Project:</b> Program X <br><b>Description:</b> Test 
        description for Project 1 <hr> <b> Start:</b> 2020/4/1 <br> <b> End:</b> 2020/8/15</p>',
        '#2B8000', 
        new Date(2020, 3, 13), 
        new Date(2020, 6, 13), 
        'link to Google Site page'
      ]);
```

Then trying to grab that data point with the selectHandler() function reference column 7 selectedItem.row, 7

```
 function selectHandler() {
          var selectedItem = chart.getSelection();
          if (selectedItem = 0) {
            var link = dataTable.getValue(selectedItem.row, 7);
            window.open(link), '_blank');
            console.log(link);
          }
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

**UPDATE**

Current state of code: Styling of rowLabel is working but click event does not work on Google Site Embed. Google Site Test Link: https://sites.google.com/view/timeline-testing/home

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script>
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['timeline']
}).then(function () {
  var container = document.getElementById('roadmap');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'Category'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'Project'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'style', role: 'style'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'Start'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'End'});

  dataTable.addRows([
    [{v: 'Category 1', p: {link: 'https://sites.google.com/view/timeline-testing/secondary-page/test-subpage'}}, 'Project 1', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 3, 13), new Date(2020, 6, 13)],
    [{v: 'Category 1', p: {link: 'https://sites.google.com/view/timeline-testing/secondary-page/test-subpage'}}, 'Project 2', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 4, 22), new Date(2020, 6, 24)],
    [{v: 'Category 1', p: {link: 'https://sites.google.com/view/timeline-testing/secondary-page/test-subpage'}}, 'Project 3', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 6, 13), new Date(2020, 9, 14)],
    [{v: 'Category 1', p: {link: 'https://www.google.com'}}, 'Project 4', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 9, 15), new Date(2020, 10, 30)],
    [{v: 'Category 2', p: {link: 'https://www.bing.com'}}, 'Project 1', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 3, 1), new Date(2020, 4, 14)],
    [{v: 'Category 2', p: {link: 'https://www.bing.com'}}, 'Project 2', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 4, 14), new Date(2020, 6, 15)],
    [{v: 'Category 2', p: {link: 'https://www.bing.com'}}, 'Project 3', 'test', '#00B0F0', new Date(2020, 4, 14), new Date(2020, 10, 30)],
    [{v: 'Category 3', p: {link: 'https://www.yahoo.com'}}, 'Project 1', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 3, 1), new Date(2020, 4, 13)],
    [{v: 'Category 3', p: {link: 'https://www.yahoo.com'}}, 'Project 2', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 3, 1), new Date(2020, 6, 10)],
    [{v: 'Category 3', p: {link: 'https://www.yahoo.com'}}, 'Project 3', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 7, 19), new Date(2020, 10, 30)],
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: (dataTable.getNumberOfRows() * 42) + 42,
    tooltip: {isHtml: true},
    legend: 'none',
    timeline: {
      rowLabelStyle: {
        color: '#3399cc'
      }
    }
  };

function readyHandler() {
    var labels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
      if (label.getAttribute('fill') === options.timeline.rowLabelStyle.color) {
        label.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
        label.setAttribute('style', 'cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;');
      }
    });
  }

  function clickHandler(sender) {
    var rowLabel = sender.target.textContent;
    var dataRows = dataTable.getFilteredRows([{
      column: 0,
      value: rowLabel
    }]);
    if (dataRows.length > 0) {
      var link = dataTable.getProperty(dataRows[0], 0, 'link');
      window.open(link, '_blank');
    }
  }

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', readyHandler);
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
});


</script>

<div id="roadmap"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case, maybe the `'select'` event is not the best solution.

instead, we can add event listeners to the row labels on the `'ready'` event.

in the options, we add a unique color to the row labels.

```
timeline: {
  rowLabelStyle: {
    color: '#3399cc'
  }
}
```

we can use the unique color to apply additional css styles.

```
#roadmap text[fill="#3399cc"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

then use that unique color to find the chart elements and add the click event listener.

```
function readyHandler() {
  var labels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
    if (label.getAttribute('fill') === options.timeline.rowLabelStyle.color) {
      label.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    }
  });
}
```

to store the link in the data table,
we can use object notation for the first column.
we can provide the value (`v:`) and the link as a property (`p:`).

```
{v: 'Category 1', p: {link: 'https://www.google.com'}}
```

then we can use the `getProperty` method to pull the link from the data table in our click handler.

first, we have to get the content of the label clicked,
and use data table method `getFilteredRows` to find which row label was clicked.

```
function clickHandler(sender) {
  var rowLabel = sender.target.textContent;
  var dataRows = dataTable.getFilteredRows([{
    column: 0,
    value: rowLabel
  }]);
  if (dataRows.length > 0) {
    var link = dataTable.getProperty(dataRows[0], 0, 'link');
    window.open(link, '_blank');
  }
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['timeline']
}).then(function () {
  var container = document.getElementById('roadmap');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'Category'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'Project'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'style', role: 'style'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'Start'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'End'});

  dataTable.addRows([
    [{v: 'Category 1', p: {link: 'https://www.google.com'}}, 'Project 1', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 3, 13), new Date(2020, 6, 13)],
    [{v: 'Category 1', p: {link: 'https://www.google.com'}}, 'Project 2', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 4, 22), new Date(2020, 6, 24)],
    [{v: 'Category 1', p: {link: 'https://www.google.com'}}, 'Project 3', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 6, 13), new Date(2020, 9, 14)],
    [{v: 'Category 1', p: {link: 'https://www.google.com'}}, 'Project 4', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 9, 15), new Date(2020, 10, 30)],
    [{v: 'Category 2', p: {link: 'https://www.bing.com'}}, 'Project 1', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 3, 1), new Date(2020, 4, 14)],
    [{v: 'Category 2', p: {link: 'https://www.bing.com'}}, 'Project 2', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 4, 14), new Date(2020, 6, 15)],
    [{v: 'Category 2', p: {link: 'https://www.bing.com'}}, 'Project 3', 'test', '#00B0F0', new Date(2020, 4, 14), new Date(2020, 10, 30)],
    [{v: 'Category 3', p: {link: 'https://www.yahoo.com'}}, 'Project 1', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 3, 1), new Date(2020, 4, 13)],
    [{v: 'Category 3', p: {link: 'https://www.yahoo.com'}}, 'Project 2', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 3, 1), new Date(2020, 6, 10)],
    [{v: 'Category 3', p: {link: 'https://www.yahoo.com'}}, 'Project 3', 'test', '#2B8000', new Date(2020, 7, 19), new Date(2020, 10, 30)],
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: (dataTable.getNumberOfRows() * 42) + 42,
    tooltip: {isHtml: true},
    legend: 'none',
    timeline: {
      rowLabelStyle: {
        color: '#3399cc'
      }
    }
  };

  function readyHandler() {
    var labels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
      if (label.getAttribute('fill') === options.timeline.rowLabelStyle.color) {
        label.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
        label.setAttribute('style', 'cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;');
      }
    });
  }

  function clickHandler(sender) {
    var rowLabel = sender.target.textContent;
    var dataRows = dataTable.getFilteredRows([{
      column: 0,
      value: rowLabel
    }]);
    if (dataRows.length > 0) {
      var link = dataTable.getProperty(dataRows[0], 0, 'link');
      //window.open(link, '_blank');
      console.log(link);
    }
  }

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', readyHandler);
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="roadmap"></div>
```

note: the chart will convert all colors in the options to lower case.
(`#3399cc`) <-- be sure to use a lower case option for the color,
less the ready handler may not be able to find the text elements...

Comment: This was really helpful - the only part that I am not able to get working from your example is the CSS Style Rule:
 #roadmap text[fill="#3399cc"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
 The Google Site I am trying to embed the code on either won't draw the code or adds the #roadmap as plain text above my chart depending if I have it within my </style> or not.

Comment: hmm, another option would be ... above in the routine where we add the event listener, you could try setting the style attribute, changed snippet above...

Comment: The styling works now - Updated my Google Site Example showing the new style being added into the Google Timeline. The actual click event and going to another page / site doesn't seem to be working. [link]https://sites.google.com/view/timeline-testing/home

Comment: you need to un-comment out that line (remove `//` at the start of `window.open`). I commented out above because it won't work on this site. you can also remove the `console` line...

Comment: Whoops, I thought I had already done that earlier. Confirmed it is working 100%. Thank you so much for the help, I've learned a lot just from trying to implement this solution.