# How to use the dynamic json data for the google gantt charts?

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization, gantt-chart

I have a problem in google Gantt chart.

Now I got the normal gantt chart with their start and end date, draft date(triangle) as mile stone by giving the hard-coded values of all the values.

I want chart by dynamically inputting the json data and should take the draft date(mile stone) dynamically from it.

I also need the column 'Task Name' data as hyperlink.

```js
 google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['gantt']
}).then(function () {
  var container = document.getElementById('gantt');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(container);

  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
      dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
      dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
      dataTable.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
      dataTable.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
     dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
     dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
     dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

      dataTable.addRows([
        ['2014Spring', 'Model 1', 'spring',
         new Date(2020, 1, 22), new Date(2020, 2, 20), null, 100, null],
       ['2014Autumn', 'Model 3', 'autumn',
         new Date(2020, 3, 21), new Date(2020, 4, 20), null, 100, null],
         ['2014Winter', 'Model 4', 'winter',
         new Date(2020, 4, 21), new Date(2020, 8, 21), null, 100, null]
   ]);

  var dateRangeStart = dataTable.getColumnRange(3);
  var dateRangeEnd = dataTable.getColumnRange(4);
  var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'MM/dd/yyyy'
  });
  var rowHeight = 45;

  var options = {
    height: ((dataTable.getNumberOfRows() * rowHeight) + rowHeight),
    gantt: {
    palette: [
      {
        "color": "#3e77ca",
        "dark": "#4cc9ac",
        "light": "#3e77ca"
      }
    ]
      
    }
    
    
    
  };

 

  function drawChart() {
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }

  function addMarker(markerRow, markerDate) {
    var baseline;
    var baselineBounds;
    var chartElements;
    var marker;
    var markerSpan;
    var rowLabel;
    var svg;
    var svgNS;
    var gantt;
    var ganttUnit;
    var ganttWidth;
    var timespan;
    var xCoord;
    var yCoord;

    // initialize chart elements
    baseline = null;
    gantt = null;
    rowLabel = null;
    svg = null;
    svgNS = null;
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('svg');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
      svg = chartElements[0];
      svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;
    }
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
      gantt = chartElements[0];
    }
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('path');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(chartElements, function(path) {
        if ((baseline === null) && (path.getAttribute('fill') !== 'none')) {
          baseline = path;
        }
      });
    }
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(chartElements, function(label) {
        if (label.textContent === markerRow) {
          rowLabel = label;
        }
      });
    }
    if ((svg === null) || (gantt === null) || (baseline === null) || (rowLabel === null) ||
        (markerDate.getTime() < dateRangeStart.min.getTime()) ||
        (markerDate.getTime() > dateRangeEnd.max.getTime())) {
      return;
    }

    // calculate placement
    ganttWidth = parseFloat(gantt.getAttribute('width'));
    baselineBounds = baseline.getBBox();
    timespan = dateRangeEnd.max.getTime() - dateRangeStart.min.getTime();
    ganttUnit = (ganttWidth - baselineBounds.x) / timespan;
    markerSpan = markerDate.getTime() - dateRangeStart.min.getTime();

    // add marker
    marker = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'polygon');
    marker.setAttribute('fill', 'transparent');
    marker.setAttribute('stroke', '#ffeb3b');
    marker.setAttribute('stroke-width', '3');
    xCoord = (baselineBounds.x + (ganttUnit * markerSpan) - 4);
    yCoord = parseFloat(rowLabel.getAttribute('y'));
    marker.setAttribute('points', xCoord + ',' + (yCoord - 10) + ' ' + (xCoord - 5) + ',' + yCoord + ' ' + (xCoord + 5) + ',' + yCoord);
    svg.insertBefore(marker, rowLabel.parentNode);
  }
 function addLiner(markerDate) {
    var baseline;
    var baselineBounds;
    var chartElements;
    var markerLabel;
    var markerLine;
    var markerSpan;
    var svg;
    var timeline;
    var timelineUnit;
    var timelineWidth;
    var timespan;

    baseline = null;
    timeline = null;
    svg = null;
    markerLabel = null;
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('svg');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
      svg = chartElements[0];
    }
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
      timeline = chartElements[0];
    }
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('path');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
      baseline = chartElements[0];
    }
    chartElements = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    if (chartElements.length > 0) {
      markerLabel = chartElements[0].cloneNode(true);
    }
    if ((svg === null) || (timeline === null) || (baseline === null) || (markerLabel === null) ||
        (markerDate.getTime() < dateRangeStart.min.getTime()) ||
        (markerDate.getTime() > dateRangeEnd.max.getTime())) {
      return;
    }

    // calculate placement
    timelineWidth = parseFloat(timeline.getAttribute('width'));
    baselineBounds = baseline.getBBox();
    timespan = dateRangeEnd.max.getTime() - dateRangeStart.min.getTime();
    timelineUnit = (timelineWidth - baselineBounds.x) / timespan;
    markerSpan = markerDate.getTime() - dateRangeStart.min.getTime();

    // add label
    markerLabel.setAttribute('fill', '#e91e63');
    markerLabel.setAttribute('y', options.height);
    markerLabel.setAttribute('x', (baselineBounds.x + (timelineUnit * markerSpan) - 4));
    markerLabel.textContent = "Today";
    svg.appendChild(markerLabel);

    // add line
    markerLine = timeline.cloneNode(true);
    markerLine.setAttribute('y', 0);
    markerLine.setAttribute('x', (baselineBounds.x + (timelineUnit * markerSpan)));
    markerLine.setAttribute('height', options.height);
    markerLine.setAttribute('width', 1);
    markerLine.setAttribute('stroke', 'none');
    markerLine.setAttribute('stroke-width', '0');
    markerLine.setAttribute('fill', '#e91e63');
    svg.appendChild(markerLine);
  }
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // add marker for current date
    addMarker('Model 1', new Date(2020, 2, 8));
    addMarker('Model 3', new Date(2020, 4, 10));
    addMarker('Model 4', new Date(2020, 5, 15));

 addLiner(new Date()); 
  });

  window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  drawChart();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="gantt"></div>
```

The expected output should be in the below format:

1. "Y axis should be a hyperlink."
2. "All the data should be dynamically loaded from JSON in the format

`{"startDate":"10-Jan-2020", "endDate":"30-Jan-2020", "draftDate":"15-Jan-2020", "ModelId":1134 } "`

3. Draft date should be in a milestone format(dynamic input from the JSON).

[image: Refer the below image:]

Comment: how are you getting the json to the page, ajax? as for the hyperlinks, you need to add those manually, _similar_ to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63073041/5090771)...

Comment: @WhiteHat yes, we are using an Ajax call for getting the json. The json looks in the above format.

Answer (score 0):

so down at the bottom of the script,
I think you would want to replace the following lines...

```
  window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  drawChart();
```

and add the ajax call there.
the dates will need to be converted to actual date objects.
and assuming the data will be coming from ajax in an array,
you would want to do something similar to the following...

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'get_data.url',
  dataType: 'JSON'
}).done(function (data) {

  data.forEach(function (row) {
    dataTable.addRow([
      row.ModelId,              // 'Task ID'
      row.Task,                 // 'Task Name'
      row.Resource,             // 'Resource'
      new Date(row.startDate),  // 'Start Date'
      new Date(row.endDate),    // 'End Date'
      null,                     // 'Duration'
      row.Percent,              // 'Percent Complete'
      null                      // 'Dependencies'
    ]);
  });

  window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  drawChart();
});
```

though, I don't see the other fields, such as Task Name & Resource,
in the example JSON posted.

Comment: I tried the same but it throws error. Can you please correct me where I am wrong. For time being I have included the json data in the code. And I want the ModelId as hyperlink. Reference - https://jsfiddle.net/wz7npscL/

Comment: please check the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart#data-format) for gantt chart. the last column, Dependencies, is a required column. but you can include `null` values if needed. and it is fine to re-name start date to draft date, but it needs to come before end date. or at least, the first date needs to be less than the second date. you can find an example for adding links in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63073041/5090771), see updated fiddle for corrections --> [https://jsfiddle.net/wb43mhy7/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/wb43mhy7/2/)

Comment: This is fine. But the addMarker and addLiner functions are not working. How to add the milestone using the draft date?

Comment: the markers /lines being added in the fiddle have dates that don't exist on the chart...

Comment: I tried having the same date for milestone, but still I am not getting the addMarker and also addLiner needs only the current date to appear,  it is also not displayed(I have given the required function). updated fiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/bofpxgey/1/

Comment: not sure, the posted question was about getting json data to the page. looking at the fiddle, the chart begins in Aug, so the current date will not be displayed. the data range on the chart needs to include the dates submitted for the markers / lines.