# How to make the Y-axis of the google gantt chart as hyperlink in Javascript/AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization, gantt-chart

I have dynamic data coming for the google gantt chart. I want to add hyperlink option for the Y-axis data  which will navigate me to the other page.

The code given below have the dynamic data. Task name in the Y-axis needs to be in an hyperlink. On-click the hyperlink it should navigate to the other page.

```
 google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['gantt']
}).then(function () {
  var container = document.getElementById('gantt');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(container);  
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      dataTable.addColumn('string', 'ModelId');
      dataTable.addColumn('string', 'TaskName');
      dataTable.addColumn('date', 'startDate');
      //dataTable.addColumn('date', 'draftDate');
      dataTable.addColumn('date', 'endDate');
      dataTable.addColumn('number', 'PercentComplete');
       dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
     dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');   
 var data = [{
"ModelId":"1034",
"TaskName": "Model 1",
"startDate":"10-Aug-2020",
"endDate":"20-Aug-2020",
"draftDate":"14-Aug-2020",
"Duration":null,
"PercentComplete":100
},
{
"ModelId":"1035",
"TaskName": "Model 2",
"startDate":"10-Sep-2020",
"endDate":"20-Dec-2020",
"draftDate":"14-Oct-2020",
"Duration":null,
"PercentComplete":100
}];
  data.forEach(function (row) {
  console.log(data);
    dataTable.addRow([
      row.ModelId,              // 'Task ID'
      row.TaskName,                 // 'Task Name'
     new Date(row.startDate),  // 'Start Date'
     // new Date(row.draftDate),      // 'Draft Date'
      new Date(row.endDate),    // 'End Date'
      row.PercentComplete,              // 'Percent Complete'
      row.Duration,
      null                       // 'Duration'
    ]);
    console.log("hii");
  });
  window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  drawChart();
  var dateRangeStart = dataTable.getColumnRange(2);
  var dateRangeEnd = dataTable.getColumnRange(3);
  var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'MM/dd/yyyy'
  });
  var rowHeight = 45;

  var options = {
    height: ((dataTable.getNumberOfRows() * rowHeight) + rowHeight),
    gantt: {
    palette: [
      {
        "color": "#4cc9ac",
        "dark": "#4cc9ac",
        "light": "#4cc9ac"
      }
    ]
      
    }
  };
  function drawChart() {
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }   
});

//HTML Code:
<html>
<body>
    <div id="gantt"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Looking forward for the answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: there are no options out of the box that will allow the axis labels to be linked. but we can manually add the links, on the chart's ready event. [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63073041/5090771) using the Timeline chart. should work the same...